# Can we use google ML for face recognition in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-mlkit

I want to know can I use google ML for face recognition, I want to compare the profile picture of the user with the picture that user will upload later on.

Note: The profile picture of the user is in firebase while the the picture I want compare will not be stored in firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Google's ML Kit contains a model for face **detection**, but not for face **recognition**. You could of course train a model for that yourself, but how to do that is a bit beyond what we can reasonably explain in an answer here.

If you want to find something for that, I recommend using your favorite search engine, as recommending off-site resources is off-topic on Stack Overflow.